# Iterate and print all of the file paths of all pdf files in a specific directory using Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#

How can I iterate and print all of the file paths of all `.pdf` files in a specific directory when using `Directory.EnumerateFiles`?

The following code only returns the path of the first `.pdf` file in the specified directory.

```
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\MyFolder", "*.pdf*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in files) {
            Console.WriteLine("File Path:{0}", file);
        }

       // Returns: 
       // C:\MyFolder\firstPdfFile.pdf
```

Again, what I want is to be able to print all of the paths of all pdfs files in a specified directory. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I'm not getting any errors, but the only thing I see in the console is the path of the first pdf found in the specified directory and I was expecting to see the path of all pdf files in that directory.

Comment: Unclear. This should work. Expand, how do you call this?

Comment: what is error you are getting right now ?

Comment: This really deserves a [mcve]. Your code is almost an mcve, so round it up with a Console Main() method. And do test that before posting.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but the only thing I see in the console is the path of the first pdf found in the specified directory and I was expecting to see the path of all pdf files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

haven't used function you written, but suggest you to try out below

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyFolder\", "*.pdf",
                                         SearchOption.AllDirectories);
// returns:
// "c:\MyFolder\fist.pdf"
// "c:\MyFolder\subdirectory\sss.pdf"
```

Comment: I want to use `EnumerateFiles` since it seem to be faster than `GetFiles`. Thanks!

Comment: @fs_tigre -as per msdn you code looks ok https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx ..seems like some  other issue

Comment: this could fail at special paths with missing access rights e.g. recyclebin

Comment: @Pranay Rana - Thank you for confirming that my code looks right. I will look at some other parts of my code.